# need a regex to match a pattern but not include a substring

Tags: regex

I am sure a similar question must have been posted here and I have gone through some of them and tried myself a lot but I am not able to create a regex for my requirement.

I need a regex that can match any string containing the word shirt or shirts but not prefixed by word t, tee or polo

For example, the following should match:

```
Full sleeve shirt
Full sleeve casual shirt
half sleeve formal shirts
```

All these must not match:

```
half sleeve polo shirt
sleeveless tshirt
yellow t shirt
t.shirt
t-shirt
black full sleeve tee shirt
```

I know that I need to look for the pattern `\bshirts?\b` to find shirt and shirts. But for excluding tee, t and polo, I am having a hard time. Studied a bit about negative lookaheads but not quite clear how to use.

Comment: What language is this for? It's doable if the regex engine for the language allows for negative lookbehinds, but even then, TBH it would be better if this weren't done with regex alone.  What is the context of the data? e.g. are these values in a column in a db table that you want to select? can more than one of these show up in the string you are matching against? etc.

Comment: Why `half sleeve polo shirt` is not a match? Which regex tool are you using?

Comment: @anubhava because OP said he didn't want to match if "polo" (2nd sentence)

Comment: this is to be implemented in python and javascript. Also, they will be coming in the title of products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python you can use this regex with multiple negative lookbehind patterns:

```
(?<!t.)(?<!tee.)(?<!polo.)\bshirts?\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH6dB4/1)

Comment: `(?<!t.)(?<!tee.)(?<!polo.)\bshirts?\b` this one is working for me. Hope I am not doing anything wrong which might hit me later?

Comment: Yes that should work in python, answer updated with your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no lookbehind in JS. You will have to use an external library in JS for that e,g, [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
^.*(?<!t|t.|tee.|polo.)\bshirts?\b
```

[This updated solution may work for you.](https://regex101.com/r/yJ5sP7/2)

Comment: @mandeep_m91 I didn't realize you needed to exclude "polo-shirt" as it wasn't part of your examples.  I've since updated my suggestion.